# SQL Index Update with Covering Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating an index on a table and I want to include a covering column: messageText nvarchar(1024)

After insertion, the messageText is never updated, so it's an ideal candidate to include in a covering index to speed up lookups.

But what happens if I update other columns in same index?

Will the entire row in the index need reallocating or will just that data from the updated column be updated in the index?

**Simple Example**

Imaging the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Messages](
    [messageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mbrIDTo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isRead] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [messageText] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL
)
```

And the following Index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_messages] ON [Messages] ( [mbrIDTo] ASC, [messageID] ASC ) 
INCLUDE ( [isRead], [messageText])
```

When we update the table:

```
UPDATE    Messages
SET       isRead = 1
WHERE     (mbrIDTo = 6546)
```

The query plan shows that the index IX_messages is utilized and will also be updated becuase the column isRead is part of the index.

Therefore does including large text fields (such as messageText in the above) as part of a covering column in an index, impact performance when other values, in that same index, are updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a row is updated in SQL Server, the entire row is deleted and a new row with the updated records is inserted.  Therefore, even if the messageText field is not changing, it will still have to be re-written to the disk.

Here is a blog post from Paul Randall with a good example: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/do-changes-to-index-keys-really-do-in-place-updates/

Comment: do you have a link to an msdn article stating that or some other reliable source?